# how to display mysql dynamic pivot table in view in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have store procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `siharpa`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `rekap_survey_ppe`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `rekap_survey_ppe`(
    TanggalAwal DATE,
    TanggalAkhir DATE
    
    )
BEGIN

    SET @sql_dinamis = (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT('SUM( IF(YEARWEEK(tanggal) = ' , YEARWEEK(tanggal) , ',h_beras_premium,0) ) AS m' , YEARWEEK(tanggal) ) ) FROM ppe WHERE tanggal BETWEEN TanggalAwal AND TanggalAkhir
    );

    SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT kecamatan.nama_kecamatan,', @sql_dinamis, ' FROM ppe JOIN kecamatan ON ppe.id_kecamatan = kecamatan.id_kecamatan GROUP BY ppe.id_kecamatan WITH ROLLUP' );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

and the result like this :

| nama_kecamatan | m202201 | m202202 | m202203 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bangsri | 12500 | 0 | 12000 |
| Batealit | 11000 | 12000 | 0 |
| Donorojo | 10500 | 0 | 0 |
| Kedung | 11000 | 0 | 0 |
| Keling | 10500 | 0 | 0 |
| Kembang | 11000 | 0 | 0 |
| Mayong | 11500 | 0 | 0 |
| Mlonggo | 13000 | 0 | 0 |
| Pakisaji | 12000 | 0 | 0 |
| Pecangaan | 11000 | 0 | 0 |
| Tahunan | 12500 | 0 | 0 |
| Welahan | 11500 | 0 | 0 |
| Welahan | 138000 | 12000 | 12000 |

and i will call my store procedure in model. but i can do viewing dynamic field on my view.
somebody can help me ?